# Extension of Fermat's two square theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. I want to show that $p$ can be expressed as $x^2+2y^2$ iff. there exists an integer $a$ such that $a^2\equiv-2 \mod p$

The 'if' part is quite simple, just by mimicking the proof of Fermat's two square theorem using the Pigeon hole principle. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197918/what-is-known-about-primes-of-the-form-x2-2y2 for a very similar one.

The 'only if' part is troubling me. I have no idea but to list out some possibilities, just for those who are interested:
$$p=3=1^2+2(1)^2, 1^2\equiv-2\mod3$$
$$p=11=3^2+2(1)^2, 3^2\equiv-2\mod11$$
$$p=83=9^2+2(1)^2, 9^2\equiv-2\mod83$$...
$$p=17=3^2+2(2)^2, 7^2\equiv-2\mod17$$
$$p=89=9^2+2(2)^2, 40^2\equiv-2\mod89$$
$$p=233=15^2+2(2)^2, 109^2\equiv-2\mod233$$
$$p=449=21^2+2(2)^2, 214^2\equiv-2\mod449$$
...
See the pattern here? Yea, but not when $y=3$...

Answer (score 0):

So the question is why if $p=x^2+2y^2$ then the congruence $t^2\equiv-2\pmod p$ is soluble ($p$ prime).

Well,
$$x^2\equiv-2y^2\pmod p.$$
Also $p\nmid y$ (why?) so there is $z$ with $yz\equiv1\pmod p$. Then
$$(xz)^2\equiv-2(yz)^2\equiv-2\pmod p.$$

Comment: wow didn't think of that. $p$ does not divide y since $y<p$, right?